# R5r allows to have cable_car in the multimodal network?

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, r5r

I am using the R5r package to compute travel time matrix calculations. I am using a GTFS from Bogotá (Colombia). This GTFS have three categories of transit: BRT, bus, and cable. I checked the validation of the GTFS, finding the cable car among all the files. However, the cable car is not considered when the GTFS is transformed into a multimodal network with WALK + TRANSIT.

Do you know if there is a way to include the cable car lines in the multimodal network?

Thank you so much

Comment: Please read about [how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. Include a sample of your data by pasting the output of `dput(<your data frame>)` into your post or `dput(head(<your data frame>))` if you have a large data frame. Also include code you have tried, any relevant errors, and expected output. If you cannot post your data, then post code for creating representative data. [Do not post images of code and/or data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6382434).

Answer (score 0):

`{r5r}` should have no problem handling cable car routes. Have you checked the service interval of the service ids that describe the operation of cable car routes? If the departure time you're using is not within this interval then the output will not include this mode.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I checked again, and the service id and service interval seem correct for the cable cars. The issue is at the beginning of the code when the function setup_r5 is used to read the GTFS and the pedestrian network to create the multimodal network. I plotted the transit network and I could not find the cable cars there. Consequently, the issue is at the start, not in the travel time computation.

Comment: It's hard to point to a problem without looking at the feed you're using, but given your feedback I'd check if the cable cars routes are in fact associated to any trips, if the trip time tables described in stop times seems coherent, if their shapes seem aligned with the stops, etc. Perhaps using `gtfstools::validate_gtfs()` can help spot any errors with the GTFS that might be causing this issue.